# Examples of sets that have infinite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A problem asked me to prove some statement, $\textbf{given that the measure of 
E is finite}$. I proved it but still don't understand why $\mu(E) <\infty$ was needed, and I think it's because I can't think of many examples of what a set with infinite measure really is.

My  first thought is just $\mathbb{R}$, because if $\mu(\mathbb{R}) = k <\infty$, then I could take the interval $(k, 2k + 1)$ would have a larger measure. So, I notice that as long as a subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, then $\mu(U) = \infty$. I can generalize this to $\mathbb{R}^n$, too. But, I can't think of any other type of infinite measure sets, not necessarily just for $\mathbb{R}^n$, since I assume that only uncountably infinite unbounded sets have infinite measure, excluding unbounded sets that "cheat" my definition of uncountable infinite and bounded like:
$$
\{x\in\mathbb{R} : x\in(0,1) \lor x\in\mathbb{N}\}
$$

Comment: At least in the usual cases for $\Bbb R^n, \Bbb C^n$, you can think of something with infinite measure as being a structure with infinite $n$-dimensional volume. For instance, in $\Bbb R$, the interval $[0,\infty)$ also has infinite measure. Another in $\Bbb R^2$ is the vertical strip $[0,1] \times \Bbb R$.

Comment: In order to understand why the hypothesis of finite measure exists, it would be helpful to know what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Also agree with what Xander said. Sometimes, the hypothesis happens to be unnecessary and the lecturer/author just wants to focus on the finite case for whatever reason. (Or perhaps the infinite case can be done, but is harder, or requires a few special assumptions.)

Comment: "So, I notice that as long as a subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, then $\mu(U) = \infty$." -- This claim is not true. The integers are unbounded but have Lebesgue measure zero. If you want uncountability, copy the Cantor set from $[0,1]$ to each $[n,n+1]$ for integer $n$ - then unbounded, uncountable, and measure zero.

Comment: "I assume that only uncountably infinite unbounded sets have infinite measure" - This is true in the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$. Any countable set, bounded or not, has measure zero. (Examples: the naturals, integers, and rationals.) Granted, as with the Cantor set, uncountability does not give you positive measure necessarily. Unboundedness is necessary (otherwise you can find a sufficiently small ball of finite measure containing the set.)

Comment: It might be useful to point out that a set can be uncountably infinite and unbounded, and yet have finite measure.

Comment: To elaborate on Brian Tung's comment, if $\lambda(X)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, we can define a new measure: $$I(X) = \mu(X \cap [0,1])$$ and in fact $I(\mathbb{R}) = 1$

Comment: @XanderHenderson  It was to prove that, if $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable sets such that $E_n\supseteq E_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then: $$  \mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n \right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(E_n)$$ and we have that $\mu(E_1) < \infty$

Comment: @Obamafish Consider $E_n = (n,\infty)$.  What is the measure of each $E_n$?  What is the intersection of the $E_n$?  What is the measure of that intersection?

Comment: @XanderHenderson The intersection of $E_n$ and $E_{n+1}$ is just $E_{n+1}$, so the infinite intersection would just be the empty set, and thus have zero measure. But, the right-hand side would still be infinity, right?

Comment: Yes.  And so...?